# Folder getting excluded after building solution

Tags: visual-studio, gulp

Trying to build a mobile application using ionic2 and angular2 / typescript in Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. gulp is being used to automate the build process. Now when I run the project the folder css is getting excluded from the project and so my css file is 404-ed. The issue as I see it is with the below code.

```
var buildSass = require('ionic-gulp-sass-build');
//code omitted
gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function(done) {
    runSequence(
        //code omitted
    );
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del('www/build');
});
```

the build folder is deleted and re-added and so it gets excluded from the project. Is that assumption correct? If so, whats a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your assumption is correct, because the callback function will be executed only after the clean task is completed.

Run Clean task inside the callback function when you have build and used all the things.

Comment: thanks. but this is a visual studio thing. it excludes the folder